# Intelligence do not detect a library when called using a 'using' statement in a Blazor App

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor-server-side

I'm new to C# and Blazor and I was creating an application based on a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DNgdphLvag&t=1969s). I created a Blazor server application and a C# Library. Now I'm trying to import the Library into the Blazor application. But it won't detect. Is there any solution to this?

My Solution has 2 projects. BlazorUIDemo and DataAccessLibrary. From the BlazorUIDemo, Startup class im calling the library as 'using DataAccessLibrary'.

Comment: Show us your code.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance.

Comment: You most probably need to add a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019) to `BlazorUIDemo` referencing `DataAccessLibrary`

Comment: Thanks @MindSwipe. Blazor projects do not have a reference file but your comment helped me to solve the issue. I added the reference to the dependency and it worked. Thanks again.